# Center frame title vertically in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

Is it possible with beamer to center the frame title vertically (as well as horizontally), together with the frame content?

That is, have the frame title and content appear together in the center of the page, with space above and below.

I am trying to mimic the default appearance of a [reveal.js presentation](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/1). I don't know where to start - every beamer theme I've found has the frame title at the top of the page.

Comment: Pass the `c` option to the frame environment: `\begin{frame}[c] ... \end{frame}`

Comment: @Jubobs I tried your suggestion, my frame title still appears at the top of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Title style is defined with `beamercolor` and `beamerfont` templates. Use them inside a `beamercolorbox` with correct dimensions or just fix them before writing the title.

If you want also horizontally centre ordered or unordered lists, use `varwidth` package.

Next is a modification of Christof's example. Adjust it to your stylish needs.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester} 
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=red!70!black!100!}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usepackage{varwidth}


\newcommand{\mytitle}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3ex,dp=1ex,center,wd=\framewidth]{frametitle}
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3ex,dp=1ex,center,wd=\framewidth]{framesubtitle}
        \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]{Frametitle}{Framesubtitle}    

\centering

\mytitle

\medskip
Some Text. Some Text. Some Text. Some Text.  Some Text. Some Text.

\medskip
\begin{varwidth}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item One Subject
\item Another Subject
\end{itemize}\end{varwidth}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My quick and dirty solution is something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{} 
\usetheme{Rochester} 
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=red!70!black!100!}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % 
% \setmainfont{Cambria} 
% \setsansfont{Calibri}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]{Frametitle}{}    
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.7\linewidth}
  \begin{center}
    \Large \textbf{\insertframetitle} \normalsize \\[1ex]
    Some Text. Some Text. Some Text. Some Text.  Some Text. Some Text.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item One Subjekt
    \item Another Subject
    \end{itemize}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but then my theme's frametitle styling isn't applied... though I guess I could stash all of that in a macro. Thanks!